# How to align matplotlib chart in its window?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to align the chart to the top and left side of the window, eleminating all the whitespace there. Also the labels on the x axis are cut-off for some reason, even though I'm using tight_layout(). On top of this I have trouble removing the scientific notation from the y axis. (I want to display the original str or float held in the variable, If I use plt.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)) I get an attribute arror: 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'yaxis'.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

```
from binance.client import Client
import time, os, csv, datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

client = Client(apikey, apisecret)

mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['ytick.right'] = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelright'] = True
plt.rcParams['ytick.left'] = plt.rcParams['ytick.labelleft'] = False

x_vars = []
y_vars = []

def animate(i):
    global x_vars
    global y_vars
    if len(x_vars) > 30:
        x_vars = x_vars[-30:] 
        y_vars = y_vars[-30:] 
    else:
        pass

    current_time = client.get_server_time()
    current_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="XRPBTC")

    trstime = current_time["serverTime"] / 1000
    time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(trstime)).strftime('%M:%S')

    x_vars.append(str(time))
    y_vars.append(float(current_price["price"]))

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x_vars, y_vars)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)  


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the y-axis to the right.:

```
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```

Don't display offset:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_yaxis().get_offset_text(), visible=False)
```

Dealing with missing ticks (disabling tight display):

```
# plt.tight_layout()
```

To confirm this, I created an animation with the binance API and checked it. Since the essence of this question is not the animation, I think you will get faster answers from more people if you focus your question only on the graph part.

full code:

```
import datetime
import json
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=XRPBTC"

mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
plt.setp(ax.get_yaxis().get_offset_text(), visible=False)

plt.style.use('ggplot')

x_vars = []
y_vars = []

def animate(i):
    global x_vars
    global y_vars
    if len(x_vars) > 30:
        x_vars = x_vars[-30:] 
        y_vars = y_vars[-30:] 
    else:
        pass
    current_time = 0
    current_price = 0
    r = requests.get(url) 
    response_dict = r.json()
    current_price = float(response_dict['price'])
    dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    ttime = '{:02}:{:02}'.format(dt_now.minute, dt_now.second)
    x_vars.append(ttime)
    y_vars.append(current_price)

    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(x_vars, y_vars)
    ax.set_xticklabels(x_vars, rotation=45)


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=30, interval=500, repeat=False)
# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve any of the 3 issues I've mentioned.

Comment: Did you run my code? Are you saying that your issue is three, including moving the y-axis to the right to two where the y-axis can be seen and the offset value cannot be deleted? Wouldn't your issue be solved with a graph by itself instead of an animation?